# Preloading an Ionic Page

Tags: ionic3

I have created a game and using ionic 3 for deploying it to mobile platforms.
I have two pages, page1 is listing page and page2 in which game runs in an iframe.
What I want to achieve is whenever a user selects a game from listing then as long as the iframe loads I want to keep the user on page1 showing loading text, and then when iframe loads completely I move to page2

Is there a way to achieve this? 
I have tried using
`this.navCtrl.insert(RoomPage, 0, {});`
to insert the RoomPage at index 0 and then using it later in listing page like this `let page: any = this.navCtrl.getByIndex(0);
page.openGameRoom(options);` but it did not work as expected. I need to load the RoomPage beforehand so that I can pass an event or call its function in some way, is there some other way to achieve functionality which I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing loading screen in Page1, you can show the loading screen in Page 2 and dismiss the loader/ loading screen, when iFrame is finished loading using:

```
<iframe (load)="myLoadEvent()" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I was handling it so far, but the requirement is to keep the user on listing page showing loading gif and when iframe in RoomPage gets completely loaded I remove the loading gif and move to RoomPage, Thanks

Comment: But how can you load your RoomPage without navigating to it. Your requirement does not satisfy Angular/Ionic Page Lifecycle. One solution is to put content of Listing Page and Room Page in ion-slides and hide listing once the iFrame is loaded.

Comment: I agree with the solution to have the listing page and RoomPage in 1 single page and having separate divs and using *ngIf to differentiate between them, but I was thinking there could be a way to load the page in background (or preload) because managing listing and game on 1 page will be difficult.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to preload iframe on a separate page. Since ionic works on Web View, WebView will draw iFrame only when it gets its code. In a similar context, you are trying to load an HTML Page without giving the browser actual HTML content.